# SPSS line chart with multiple variables

Tags: charts, spss

How can I build a line chart with the frequency distributions of 3 variables?  They have similar ranges of values.  I'm using SPSS 19 basic under Windows 8.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of reshaping the data so all three variables are in the same column and then mapping the lines to different colors. So first lets make some fake data.

```
SET SEED 10.
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP #i = 1 TO 100.
  COMPUTE X = #i.
  COMPUTE Y1 = RV.NORMAL(2,1).
  COMPUTE Y2 = RV.NORMAL(7,1).
  COMPUTE Y3 = RV.NORMAL(12,1).
  END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
```

Now it is possible to make a chart like you want in the current shape of the data, but a generally useful approach is to reshape the data so all three `Y` variables are in the same column and have a second categorical variable, `Var`, distinguish the original variable. (The `FORMATS` command is to make the labels in the chart look nicer in this example.)

```
VARSTOCASES /MAKE Y FROM Y1 TO Y3 /INDEX Var (Y).
FORMATS X Y (F3.0).
```

Now we can build the graph, this is pretty close to what the GUI spit out (I edited the Y axis to have a minimum of -1).

```
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=X Y Var 
    MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: X=col(source(s), name("X"))
  DATA: Y=col(source(s), name("Y"))
  DATA: Var=col(source(s), name("Var"), unit.category())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("X"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Y"))
  GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), label("Var"))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), min(-1))
  ELEMENT: line(position(X*Y), color.interior(Var))
END GPL.
```

[image]

Comment: Andy W, Thanks, this is very close to what I need.  I am a cold newbie to GGRAPH, but I don't think I need the VARSTOCASES command since the 3 vars are based on the same data. I have the height and gender for each case.  I want to have a graph for the frequencies of height for males, for females, and for all.  I created 2 new vars, one for height of males the other for females. I think all I really need is the GGRAPH and GPL to put them all in the same chart.

Comment: OK, I figured out the basics: